# Minimum permission needed for GRANT CRUD ON

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, certificate

I have a certificate set up to do cross database CRUD operations.  The certificate is linked to a user in each destination database.  I sign any stored procedures in the source database with the certificate, and grant the CRUD access to the user in the destination database.  Everything works fine with this setup.

We recently hired a couple of developers to help with the workload, and they are now creating stored procedures that need to be signed.  I found that by giving them `CONTROL` of the certificate, they are able to sign the stored procedures in the source database.

However, they aren't able to grant CRUD access to the user in the destination database.  Is there a way I can allow them to do that without giving them `db_owner` or `db_securityadmin` in the destination database?  Is there a better way to manage this task?